# Insertion in ordered linked list with omiting duplicate nodes

Tags: c, linked-list

I am trying to build an ordered linked list with out the possibility of finding duplicate data in the new ordered list. Say `f_total` have this values:
`f_total: 48 42 45 50 42 48 48 43`
The new linked list should be look like this:
`42 43 45 48 50`

*Code updated:*

```
        typedef struct _sigma {
            int algo;
            int f;
            int c;
            node_p list;
            struct _sigma *next;
        } sigma, *sigma_p;

        sigma_p sigma_tmp = NULL;
        sigma_p sigma_new = NULL;
        sigma_p sigma_optimal = NULL;
        int f_total = 0;

        f_total = exectasks(m, nod_tmp, &c_max, &cmin); // f_total will be updated after each time exectasks function return.
        ...
        if(sigma_optimal == NULL)
        {
            sigma_optimal = (sigma *)malloc(sizeof(sigma));
            sigma_optimal->algo = 0;
            sigma_optimal->f = f_optimal;
            sigma_optimal->c = cmin;
            sigma_optimal->list = nod_tmp;
            sigma_optimal->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            sigma_new = (sigma *)malloc(sizeof(sigma));
            sigma_new->algo = 0;
            sigma_new->f = f_optimal;
            sigma_new->c = cmin;
            sigma_new->list = nod_tmp;
            sigma_tmp = sigma_optimal;
            while(sigma_tmp != NULL && f_optimal > sigma_tmp->f)
            {
                sigma_prev = sigma_tmp;
                sigma_tmp = sigma_tmp->next;
            }  

            if(sigma_tmp != NULL)
            {
                if(sigma_tmp->f != f_optimal)
                {
                    if(sigma_tmp == sigma_optimal)
                    {
                        sigma_new->next = sigma_optimal;
                        sigma_optimal = sigma_new;
                    }
                    else if(sigma_tmp->next == NULL)
                    {
                        sigma_prev->next = sigma_new;
                        sigma_new->next = sigma_tmp;
                    }
                    else if(sigma_tmp == NULL)
                    {
                        sigma_tmp->next = sigma_new;
                        sigma_new->next = NULL;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

But here I have two problems:

1. It does not order the list correctly.
2. It does not remove all the
   duplication.

Comment: What do you think is the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sounds like just one problem... your algorithm. Where is the definition of `f_total`, and of your "sigma" structure?

Comment: @templatetypedef I tried many ways, but all seems give incorrect result, this is the best I got so far. I am with it up 2 days to now.

Comment: nitpick: `>=` is short for `>` `||` `==`. Scan the list for the insertion position, this should be your first while loop.  Then insert.  Write down your algorithm, step through it.

Comment: Have you tried to walk through your code by hand thinking of every line how it will be executed and what will happen? - I'm just asking because all of us have to do the very same actually.

Comment: @junix Yes, I already did.

Comment: @SIFE sorry, but I don't believe that you did this seriously. Using your very own test series from your question I can tell you for example that the insertion of duplicates is not prevented by your code. To make it shorter try insertion of following pattern: `48 42 48` Which path does the third insertion take through your code?

Comment: @junix I forgot to update my code, now I am getting `Segmentation fault: 11 (core dumped).`

Comment: 1) your initial list is unordered, to find duplicates, you either have to first sort it, or use two nested loops to find the duplicates. (or use a hashtable)

Comment: @wildplasser As far as I understand, he is not getting "the list" at once. He gets the list piece by piece and is creating his linked list from it.

Comment: Well, we are both guessing, I guess. The code fragment is both incomplete and too large, and the text does not help much either.

Comment: @SIFE First of all: You are creating memory leaks as you are not freeing elements you do not insert in the list. Secondly: Where do you make sure that ->next of your newly allocated element is NULL?

Comment: @junix With all my respect, you giving notes on the fly, if you see some wrong, pointing to it will be nice, rather then leaving me guess.

Comment: @SIFE I give you clues so YOU can walk through your code yourself and knowing what you are looking for. In fact I want YOU to look through the code yourself and I want YOU to think about the errors YOU made yourself. I know this is unconvenient for you at the moment (so it is for me as you tend to not go further than told) but it will help you solving such problems in the future, trust me. So again, the clue is: If there is already an element of the list (say 50) and you put in something <50 what happens to ->next? And what happens to ->next if you put in something >50?

Comment: @junix You are getting it now worse :). I updated my code, putting gdb in action make some thinks more clear, now if I insert an ordered sequence(39 48 52 57), I get incomplete and unordered list, but if I inserted the sequence unordered, the list will be ordered as I expect.

Comment: @SIFE I would say we make progress. Anyway something is strange with your code as f_optimal is nowhere set. I assume it's an artefact of renaming f_total... Let me also say I'm a bit disappointed as you still don't try to verify your code yourself... Think of inserting `42 43 45` one after the other. Say we already inserted `42` and now insert `43` what does your code do?

Comment: @junix `f_optimal` start as `f_optimal = f_total`, then I run check with new returned value from `exectask`, `if(f_optimal > f_total) f_optimal = f_total`, but I think `f_total` is not important here. I verified my code, please reread my last comment, as I told, if I insert the elements in unordered sequence, I get the right list, otherwise I get some time one element, and some time half the list, depends on the elements I put.

Comment: @SIFE Verify your code with the following sequence: Insert 42, then insert 43. If you are too lazy to emulate the code in your mind, just fire up the debugger and step through it. Pay attention to the values of the pointers after the while loop exits.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23666/discussion-between-junix-and-sife)

Comment: Why voting to close my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fix it:

```
    f_total = exectasks(m, nod_tmp, &c_max, &cmin); // f_total will be updated after each time exectasks function return.
    ...
    if(sigma_optimal == NULL) // the start of the list
    {
        sigma_optimal = (sigma *)malloc(sizeof(sigma));
        sigma_optimal->algo = 0;
        sigma_optimal->f = f_optimal;
        sigma_optimal->c = cmin;
        sigma_optimal->list = nod_tmp;
        sigma_optimal->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        sigma_new = (sigma *)malloc(sizeof(sigma));
        sigma_new->algo = 0;
        sigma_new->f = f_optimal;
        sigma_new->c = cmin;
        sigma_new->list = nod_tmp;
        sigma_tmp = sigma_optimal;
        while(sigma_tmp != NULL && f_optimal > sigma_tmp->f)
        {
            sigma_prev = sigma_tmp;
            sigma_tmp = sigma_tmp->next;
        }  

        if(f_optimal != sigma_tmp->f && sigma_tmp != NULL)
        {
            if(sigma_tmp == sigma_optimal) // we are in the head
            {
                sigma_new->next = sigma_tmp;
                sigma_optimal = sigma_tmp; // update the new head list
            }
            else // we are some where in the middle
            {
                sigma_prev->next = sigma_new;
                sigma_new->next = sigma_tmp;
            }
        }

        if(sigma_tmp == NULL) // we are in the end
        {
            sigma_prev->next = sigma_new;
            sigma_new->next = NULL;
        }
    }
```